# Yii2 - Dropdownlist to load other attributes

Tags: yii2

I have this Model Class

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('course', 'ID'),
        'course_code' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Code'),
        'course_type' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Type'),
        'course_title' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Title'),
        'course_unit' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Unit'),
    ];
}
```

On Dropdownlist change, I want to load and display course_code, course_type, course_title, and course_unit. But should only save course_title. The other should only be displayed and not save, except course_title.

Am ableto display only course_title. This is my view for the dropdown list.

```
<?= $form->field($modelDetail, "course_id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(app\modules\course\models\CourseMaster::find()->where(['is_status'=>0])->all(),'id','course_title'),
'language' => 'en',
'options' => ['placeholder' => '--- Select Course ---',
],
'pluginOptions' => [
'allowClear' => true
],
]); ?>
```

This is what I have done.

[image: dropdown1]

But I want to achieve this.

[image: dropdown2]

How do I display other attributes as textInput() or label without saving in database. Thanks

**Controller**

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $modelDetail = new CourseMaster();

if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $modelDetail->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($modelDetail);
    }

    if ($modelDetail->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $modelDetail->attributes = $_POST['CourseMaster'];
    if($modelDetail->save())
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    else
        return $this->render('create', ['modelDetail' => $modelDetail,]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'modelDetail' => $modelDetail,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to display the remaining attributes on the selection of any option in drop-down. you should bind `onchange` method and throw an ajax call to a action where you wll load a view containing three fields and before you load the view select the appropriate model against the `course_id` that you will send via ajax call , i dont get the other part where you say tha **i want to save the course title only** to which model you are saving this form? add complete view and controller code

Comment: **i want to save the course title only** what this means is that I want to save only course_title to the database, while the others are for display purpose. 2. Can you give me a sample of how I can use ajax to bind onchange method against course_id. **I have added the Controller**

Comment: your `actionCreate` does not look like loding the form you have added as it does not seem to pass the `$modelDetail` ? where is it coming from ? which model is it

Comment: You can append(concatenate) whatever filed you want to display with DropDown. Secondary @MuhammadOmerAslam suggests, use Ajax and display the data.

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam . Am sorry, it was a mistake. It is **$modelDetail ** and not **$model*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only display other fields without sending it on form submit, you can mark field as `disabled`:

```
<?= $form->field($modelDetail, 'course_code')->textInput([
    'disabled' => true,
]) ?>
```

This will render input which cannot be edited directly and it will not be sent on form submit.

Comment: he wants the relevant field to be show when he selects a course title and then want to save the `course_title` only and that is also not confirmed into which model

Answer (score 0):

Well You can concat the data in the label of dropdown itself, will be an easier option. Use closure on the third argument in ArrayHelper::map($array, $from, $to, $group = null) as follows.

```
ArrayHelper::map(
  app\modules\course\models\CourseMaster::find()->where(['is_status'=>0])->all(),
  'id',
  function($model){
    return $model['course_title']." - ".$model['course_code'];
  }
)
```